# How to find out the running time of my service in Android?

Tags: android, service, time

I want to know , how can i find out the running time of our Service in Android. I mean , we can see the running time of our service in the **Settings - > App - > Running** , so how can i do this programmatically in our app.

So , that we can see how long our service is running?

Please suggest me , some solution , how can we do it? is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Save current time at service startup:

```
private int startTime;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    ...
}

public int getRunningTimeMillis() {
    return System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
}
```

Comment: like a complete list of running service and current timer

Comment: Just call `getRunningTimeMillis()` periodically and update some UI control with returned value.

Comment: If app is removed from recent apps after some time like 1 min then service restarted and onCreate will call again and start time will change here. This  means we will loose 1 min but running time in  Settings - > App - > Running will not change it will show 1 min included time.